# Export QuickReport to Excel xlsx format

Tags: delphi, quickreports

We need to export a QuickReport so that it can be opened with the latest Excel 2010 in xlsx format.  [This link](http://forum.quickreport.co.uk/default.aspx?g=posts&t=71) provides a solution.  But it did not work for us.

Anyone have ideas?

**UPDATE**

- The version we are using is QuickReports 5 - We just got it.
- Clarification of "does not work".  The filter allows the report to be saved with an xml extension.  And inspecting the file it is valid xml data.  But we also inspected a **xlsx** file.  But it does not look the same.

Comment: I have a couple. :) 1) Be more specific about problems than "did not work" - it's not helpful at all. 2) Specify which version of Quick Reports you're using, as the right answer might depend on that information.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a third party product like [Gnostice eDocEngine](http://www.gnostice.com/eDocEngine_VCL.asp).  It would allow you to export to .xls.  If you were feeling particularly masochistic you could do some sort of COM automation to convert the report yourself (i.e. parse the report and fill in the appropriate cells in excel)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dumb question, but are you **quite** sure you need to do this? New versions of Excel can still open old-fashioned .XLS files.

As for the "XML" exporter you linked to "not working", I think you've misunderstood what it does. It writes an XML file suitable for use with Excel's XML importer. This is very different to an .XLSX format file,

Comment: problems with unicode and ascii. the conversion convert the text to gibrish.